# Find all rows with no matching result SQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join

I have one table that contains first name and last name of employees in my company, and a field that determines whether they are still working for the company.

I have another table with contains list of tasks for the employees - It also contains two field with first and last name of the employee (- and yes, I know that's not a good structure).

I want to be able to find all employees that are still working for the company but have no tasks using MySQL query.

Any ideas?

Comment: Both table are related with any key or not

Comment: Apparently first name and last name are their key.

Comment: They are related - With the first name and last name field.

Its worth mentioning I have in the employees table about 43,000 rows and in the tasks table about 55,000 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE still_working_for_company
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT TRUE
  FROM tasks
  WHERE tasks.firstname = employees.firstname
  AND tasks.lastname = employees.lastname
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this--

```
select * from FirstTable where firstTable.employee='yes' and 
     firstTable.empid IN (select secondTbl.empId where firstTable.empid = secondTbl.empId)
```

Query is not tested and assume that your second table (task table) contain employee data only when task is assign.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM emp e 
LEFT JOIN emptask et ON e.firstname = et.firstname AND e.lastname = et.lastname 
WHERE e.stillworks = 'y' AND et.taskid IS NULL 
GROUP BY e.firstname, e.lastname
```